# Firmware over the air (FOTA)

Tags: linux, open-source, embedded-systems, firmware

I am looking for an open-source (my target is MIPS, so I will probably have to recompile) Linux implementation of [FOTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-air_programming) .
Whenever I change the application which is running remotely on a bunch of small embedded devices, for bug-fixes, new features, etc, I need a way to get the new application and possibly some configuration files onto the remote devices. 
I don’t care if it is push or pull, although pull is probably easier, with the devices polling a central server regularly. They currently send telemetry data, so the server could mention new firmware in its acknowledgement, and the device then initiate FOTA. The devices don’t currently listen for instructions from the server (it’s Telemetry, not SCADA).
Some level of security would obviously be nice, maybe Public Key, to prevent hacking.
As would handling interrupted downloads. It might depend on the (often limited) free space on the device, as to whether to:

- Delete the app, and download the new on in its place – if space is tight
- Download the new app, CRC/MD5 it, and only then delete the old and move the new into its place
  Any other standard FOTA stuff is welcome, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting this question a mere two hours ago, I have been searching again (as I did before posting, obviously :-) and have found one which I previously overlooked and which looks very promising : [RUAC](https://rauc.io/)

> RAUC is a lightweight update client that runs on your Embedded Linux device and reliably controls the procedure of updating your device with a new firmware revision. RAUC is also the tool on your host system that lets you create, inspect and modify update artifacts for your device.
>
> RAUC uses X.509 cryptography to sign your update bundles

It is free and has [copious documentation](https://rauc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

I will investigate further and update this answer if I find anything, in order to hep others in the future.

Does anyone know of something similar, but with more features?

---

[Update] RUAC might be a little too heavy duty for me personally, although it looks excellent.

I am now working my way through the most starred (upvoted) [FOTA on GitHub](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=fota&s=stars&type=Repositories).